# Error: response status is 500

Tags: c#

Buen día comunidad, estoy aprendiendo a programar, estoy construyendo un Web APIs RESTful con ASP.NET Core6,  al momento de correr la aplicación en el Swagger me sale un Error: response status is 500 cuando el Post llamo un AutorId que si existe :[Libros Post[image: ][1]]
[[image: Autores Get][2]]

[image: Error 500]

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. 
Las preguntas del tipo "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas, ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato del sitio.
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el sitio y de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
También estaría bien que revisaras [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que recibas respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Recuerda que puedes [edit] tu pregunta cuantas veces sea necesario (incluso si termina cerrada) y añadir la info relevante a forma de [Ejemplo mínimo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
(en los comentarios no se ve bien el código y abajo sólo van nuestros intentos de respuesta).

Comment: Gracias Alvaro, podría enviar mi repositorio para que lo puedan entender?

Comment: La pregunta es autocontenida como explican los enlaces que te compartí. Si mañana o después cambias el repo o lo borras, la pregunta ya no le servirá a nadie con el mismo problema. El Ejemplo mínimo es la clave.

Comment: error 500 es de tu servidor , a lo que veo, estas tratando de agregar un nuevo libro, a una tabla que no existe, `invalid object name Libros`, podrias compartir tu repositorio o el codigo del metodo en donde haces la insercion

Comment: Hola Daniel, gracias te paso mi repositorio haber si me puedes ayudar: https://github.com/Cael15/WebApiAutores.git

Comment: Estimado Daniel, logre arreglar el problema, corregí algunas referencias incorrectas en la clase LibrosController con respecto al ApplicationDbContext. ya que esta línea no compilaba:

return await context.Libros.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id);

Pues en el "AplicationDBContext" tenia : public DbSet<Libro> Libro { get; set; } . pues faltaba la s al final de Libro. Por tanto, cambie la línea de LibrosController por:

return await context.Libro.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Id == id); y funciono gracias por tu apoyo Daniel